# How to make a subprocess object save output to a temporary file and then obtain values from temporary file?

Tags: python, subprocess, temporary-files

I am currently using a Unix-based executable within my Python code in order to analyze some DNA sequences. After running the analysis, this particular executable the writes the output to a file, which is then read by my code and has the relevant values acquired from it.

Since the file is not needed for anything apart from yielding some values, I decided to make it a temporary file that would be deleted after the necessary information was acquired from it. However, my efforts to set up the code to accomplish this has proved fruitless.

```
import subprocess as sb
import tempfile

def calculate_complex_mfe(DNA_seq):
    complex_seq= str(DNA_seq)
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile as mfefile:
        p= sb.Popen(['/Users/john/Documents/Biology/nupack3.0.6/bin/mfe', '-T', '41'], stdin=sb.PIPE, stdout=sb.PIPE, env=my_env)
        strb = (mfefile+'\n'+ complex_seq + '\n').encode('utf-8')
        data = p.communicate(input=strb)
        mfe= float(open(mfefile+'.mfe').readlines()[14])
    return mfe
```

I should note that the strb variable is set up to match the formatting required for the executable to run. Also for what it's worth, the original code I used that functioned properly is posted below.

```
def calculate_complex_mfe(DNA_seq):
    complex_seq= str(DNA_seq)
    filename= "mfe-file"
    p= sb.Popen(['/Users/john/Documents/Biology/nupack3.0.6/bin/mfe', '-T', '41'], stdin=sb.PIPE, stdout=sb.PIPE, env=my_env)
    strb = (filename+'\n'+ complex_seq + '\n').encode('utf-8')
    data = p.communicate(input=strb)
    mfe= float(open(filename+'.mfe').readlines()[14])
    return mfe
```

Can anybody tell me how I can create a temporary file for the output of an executable so I can obtain some value(s) from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', buffering=-1, encoding=None, newline=None, suffix='', prefix='tmp', dir=None, delete=True)
>       Create and return a temporary file.
>
> Returns an object with a file-like interface; the name of the file
>       is accessible as file.name.  The file will be automatically deleted
>       when it is closed unless the 'delete' argument is set to False.

You don't need a file handle to write to, you just need to create a temporary file *name*, not open a temporary file. Just replace:

```
filename= "mfe-file"
```

by

```
filename = tempfile.mktemp()
```

in your second snippet to generate a temporary file name (full path) for you

Don't forget to `os.remove(filename)` it when you're done with it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But that code won't run because the line `os.remove(filename)` yields an error `no such file or directory`. I have tried to replace `filename` with a variable representing the file path to where the file would be stored, but it still does not function. How can I ameliorate this?

Comment: Ok I got it to work now... I had to add in `filename = tempfile.mktemp(dir= current_directory)` and also add `os.remove(filename+'.mfe')` in order to get the code to work in the end.